# How NOT to use Ninject's Kernel as a resource locator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am fairly new to Ninject as well and DI in general. I use NHibernate as my ORM for my MVC app and have been quite happy with my results. That is, until I upgraded from Ninject 2.1 to 2.2.

Now, I get errors within my NinjectWebsiteApplication class due to using Ninject’s Kernel as a resource locator.

Example:

```
 void NinjectWebsiteApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     ILogger logger = Kernel.Get<ILogger>();
     logger.Debug(“**********REQUEST BEGIN****************”);
     logger.Debug(“**** URL = ” + Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
 }
```

Example 2:

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    var bootstrapper = Kernel.Get<Bootstrapper>();
    bootstrapper.RegisterAllAreas();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ......
    (More stuff here, like AutoMapper mappings, etc.)
    ......
}
```

*The `Bootstrapper` class is a class I created where I register my routes, global filters, etc.

In both of the above examples, I receive a warning about the `Kernel.Get()` functions that states the following:

> 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication.Kernel' is obsolete: "Do not use Ninject as Service Locator"

After conducting several searches on this, the general consensus is that this is true.

I am trying to work around this, but am at a bit of a loss as to what to do.

I loaded the newest Ninject.Web.Mvc NuGet package which creates the NinjectMVC3 static class under the App_Start folder. I see that they're referencing `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper`, but I don't see where that fits in to what I'm trying to do.

If anyone has any hints that will help me fix my little mess, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to deal with the first is not to use the `NinjectWebsiteApplication_BeginRequest` event but to write a custom global action filter:

```
public class LogActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public LogActionFilterAttribute(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _logger.Debug("**********REQUEST BEGIN****************");
        _logger.Debug("**** URL = " + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
    }
}
```

and then in your `App_Start/NinjectMVC3.cs`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<Logger>();
    kernel.BindFilter<LogActionFilterAttribute>(FilterScope.Global, 1);
}
```

Don't forget to add `using Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax;` in order to bring the `BindFilter<>` extension method into scope.

And since you have access to the kernel inside the `RegisterServices` method which happens at application startup you could wire up everything else including your bootstrapper, ...

As far as your `Global.asax` is concerned you no longer use any Ninject specific stuff in it. You should not derive from `NinjectApplication`.

The WebActivator infrastructure allows you to have a separate initialization method.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I see understand how the log action filter works for begin requests, but what about end requests? For instance, I have the following (also disposes my IUnitOfWork):
    void NinjectWebsiteApplication_EndRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        ILogger logger = Kernel.Get<ILogger>();
        IUnitOfWork uow = Kernel.Get<IUnitOfWork>();
        uow.Displose();
        logger.Debug("************REQUEST END************");
}

Comment: @JoelHulen, you simply override either the `OnActionExecuted` or the `OnResultExecuted` method in the custom action filter the same way I showed the `OnActionExecuting` method depending on where do you want to dispose your unit of work: either after the action has finished executing or the view has finished rendering. Also if you are going to dispose your UoF you probably shouldn't be calling the attribute `LogActionFilterAttribute`. You could create another one for doing the disposal.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks! In your opinion, as far as disposing the UoW, is there a preference disposing OnActionExecuted over OnResultExecuted? Also, do you know of a way for a controller action to "opt out" of the global filter attribute?

Comment: @JoelHulen, this will depend on whether you would need the UoW in the view. Normally you shouldn't thus disposing in the `OnActionExecuted` seems better. The shorter an UoW, the better. As far as opting out from a global action attribute it is perfectly possible using Ninject's BindFilter syntax. You can chain with `When` afterwards and define conditions that must be satisfied in order to apply the filter. And if you don't use Ninject you could write a custom filter provider and still achieve the same effect.